# Adding a tag to wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, walker

I am using wp_nav_menu and I have a need for custom implementation. The default markup is like this:

```
<ul>
   <li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59"><a href="http://j2designpartnership.com/yip/about/">About</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                <li id="menu-item-60" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60"><a href="http://j2designpartnership.com/yip/about/alumni-board-members/">Alumni Board Members</a></li>
         </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69"><a href="http://j2designpartnership.com/yip/partners/">Partners</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I need there to be a span tag before the closing ul like so:

```
     <span></span>
<ul>
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this using a walker or other function?

Answer (score 1):

Its in the wp_nav_menu arguments:  `'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s<span></span></ul>'`

Comment: Yet still adding `<span>` tag in this place isn't very good idea - it makes your HTML code invalid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all... I don't think that this is a good idea. Placing `<span>` just before closing `</ul>` tag will make this HTML incorrect ;)

But if you really really (really) must and there is no other way... You can use `wp_nav_menu_items` filter to do this.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {
  return $items . '<span></span>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_wp_nav_menu_items');
```